# Is "Shift + Insert" common in Outlook?

Tags: windows-xp, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-outlook-2003

Today I accidentally hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> in **Windows XP Service Pack 3** with **Outlook 2003**. An email message form popped up with the latest clipboard entry already inserted into the body of the message. **Is this common to all versions of Outlook?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> is actually a Windows command for Paste that dates from at least Windows 3.1.  It is valid in just about any Windows application, but in the case of Outlook, you had text that Outlook knew how to enter in a message, so it assumed that's what you wanted to do.

FYI, similar commands to the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd>  for **Paste** are: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> for **Copy** and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> for **Cut**.

Comment: Been in use since *AT LEAST* DOS 5.0

Comment: @Luke I only remember using cut/copy/paste since I was a Windows user, but Wikipedia backs you up.  This was actually the standard from _before_ Windows.  When Windows came out, they adopted the Mac version of editing controls and introduced Ctrl+V, et. al.  I know the old way mostly because I'm a Dvorak keyboard user, so the "new" editing keys don't make sense on my layout.

Answer (score 4):

They're part of IBM's [CUA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Common_User_Access) from the (late) DOS era.

Answer (score 0):

Works in Outlook 2010. Can't find any documentation on this keyboard shortcut, but it works.